# Why use KL-divergence in any practical setting?

Tags: probability, entropy

The KL-divergence, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Definition, is defined as the expectation of the logarithmic difference of the probabilities of two distributions.

I understand that this construct is theoretically interesting .... but, for **practical purposes of comparing one distribution to another**, is this really a useful metric?

First of all, it fails some very obvious criteria: it is asymmetric (KL-divergence of $P$ to $Q$ is not necessarily the same as the KL-divergence of $Q$ to $P$), it also does not satisfy the triangle inequality, but I think worse of all is the fact that it involves log-differences, which are unable to capture large deviations.

Basically my question is, if I have two distributions and I want to "compare" them, why should I ever use this construct? I would prefer something like MSE.

Comment: A comparable metric that has become widely used in the machine learning community is [cross-entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy). You might find that this is also worth looking into

Comment: See as well Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.

Comment: It's obviously not meant to be symmetrical because conditional probabilities are not. It's like asking "why is set difference not symmetrical"? And Wikipedia discusses a symmetrized version in the "symmetrised divergence" section. (N.B. you can obviously construct a symmetric set difference as well.)

Comment: In general a [divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_(statistics)) is not symmetrical (of which KL is a particular case). I suppose your question is thus why bother with this notion.